# Slow indexing of cython memoryview

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, cython, memoryview

I have a very sparse matrix, say 5000x3000, double precision floats. 80% of this matrix are zeros. I need to compute a sum of each row. All of that in python/cython. I wanted to speed up the process. Because I need to compute this sum a few million times, I thought that if I make indices of non zero elements and sum only them it will be faster. The result turns to be much slower than original "brute-force" summation of all zeros.

Here a minimal example:

```
#cython: language_level=2
import  numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import time


cdef int Ncells = 5000, KCells = 400, Ne= 350
cdef double x0=0.1, x1=20., x2=1.4, x3=2.8, p=0.2

# Setting up weight
all_weights = np.zeros( (Ncells,KCells) )
all_weights[  :Ne,   :Ne ] = x0
all_weights[  :Ne, Ne:   ] = x1  
all_weights[Ne:  ,   :Ne ] = x2
all_weights[Ne:  , Ne:   ] = x3  
all_weights = all_weights * (np.random.rand(Ncells,KCells) < p)

# Making a memory view
cdef np.float64_t[:,:] my_weights = all_weights

# make an index of non zero weights
x,y    = np.where( np.array(my_weights) > 0.)  
#np_pawid  = np.column_stack( (x   ,y   ) )
np_pawid  = np.column_stack( (x   ,y   ) ).astype(int)
cdef np.int_t[:,:] pawid = np_pawid

# Making vector for column sum
summEE = np.zeros(KCells)
# Memory view
cdef np.float64_t [:] my_summEE = summEE
cdef int cc,dd,i

# brute-force summing
ntm = time.time()
for cc in range(KCells):
    my_summEE[cc] = 0
    for dd in range(Ncells):
        my_summEE[cc] += my_weights[dd,cc]
stm = time.time()
print "BRUTE-FORCE summation        : %f s"%(stm-ntm)

my_summEE[:] = 0
# summing only non zero indices
ntm = time.time()
for dd,cc in pawid:
    my_summEE[cc] += my_weights[dd,cc]
stm = time.time()
print "INDEX summation              : %f s"%(stm-ntm)

my_summEE[:] = 0
# summing only non zero indices unpacked by zip
ntm = time.time()
for dd,cc in zip(pawid[:,0],pawid[:,1]):
    my_summEE[cc] += my_weights[dd,cc]
stm = time.time()
print "ZIPPED INDEX summation       : %f s"%(stm-ntm)

my_summEE[:] = 0
# summing only non zero indices unpacked by zip
ntm = time.time()
for i in range(pawid.shape[0]):
    dd = pawid[i,0]
    cc = pawid[i,1]
    my_summEE[cc] += my_weights[dd,cc]
stm = time.time()
print "INDEXING over INDEX summation: %f s"%(stm-ntm)

# Numpy brute-froce summing
ntm = time.time()
sumwee = np.sum(all_weights,axis=0)
stm = time.time()
print "NUMPY BRUTE-FORCE summation  : %f s"%(stm-ntm)

#>
print
print "Number of brute-froce summs  :",my_weights.shape[0]*my_weights.shape[1]
print "Number of indexing    summs  :",pawid.shape[0]
#<
```

I ran it on  Raspberry Pi 3, but it seems the same results on PC too.

```
BRUTE-FORCE summation        : 0.381014 s
INDEX summation              : 18.479018 s
ZIPPED INDEX summation       : 3.615952 s
INDEXING over INDEX summation: 0.450131 s
NUMPY BRUTE-FORCE summation  : 0.013017 s

Number of brute-froce summs  : 2000000
Number of indexing    summs  : 400820

NUMPY BRUTE-FORCE in Python  : 0.029143 s
```

Can anyone explain why is cython code 3-4 time slower than numpy? Why is indexing, which reduces the number of summations from 2000000 to 400820, 45 times slower? It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're outside a function so accessing global variables. This means that Cython has to check they exist each time they're accessed, unlike function locals which it knows can't be accessed from elsewhere.
2. By default Cython handles negative indices and does bounds checking. You can [turn these off in a number of ways](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives). An obvious way is to add `@cython.wraparound(False)` and `@cython.boundscheck(False)` as decorators to your function definition. Be aware of what these actually do - the only turn off these features on `cdef`ed numpy arrays or typed memoryviews and don't apply to much else (so don't just apply them everywhere as a cargo-cult type thing).

A good way to see where issues might be is to run `cython -a <filename>` and look at the annotated html file. Areas with yellow are potentially not optimized, and you can expand the lines to see the underlying C code. Obviously only worry about frequently called functions and loops in this respect - the fact your code to setup the Numpy arrays contains Python calls is expected and not a problem.

---

A few measurements:

As you wrote it

```
BRUTE-FORCE summation        : 0.008625 s
INDEX summation              : 0.713661 s
ZIPPED INDEX summation       : 0.127343 s
INDEXING over INDEX summation: 0.002154 s
NUMPY BRUTE-FORCE summation  : 0.001461 s
```

In a function

```
BRUTE-FORCE summation        : 0.007706 s
INDEX summation              : 0.681892 s
ZIPPED INDEX summation       : 0.123176 s
INDEXING over INDEX summation: 0.002069 s
NUMPY BRUTE-FORCE summation  : 0.001429 s
```

In a function with boundscheck and wraparound off:

```
BRUTE-FORCE summation        : 0.005208 s
INDEX summation              : 0.672948 s
ZIPPED INDEX summation       : 0.124641 s
INDEXING over INDEX summation: 0.002006 s
NUMPY BRUTE-FORCE summation  : 0.001467 s
```

My suggestions do help, but not too dramatically. My differences aren't as dramatic as you see (even for your unchanged code). Numpy still wins - at a guess:

1. I suspect it's multithreading.
2. a direct sum over a whole array will have predictable patterns of memory access, which may make it more efficient than a smaller number of operations with unpredictable memory access

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, my code is inside cdef function with proper type definitions. It doesn't change anything. I posted a minimal example, to show the issue.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I've added some timings in, which show that my changes do help, but probably not as much as you want. I don't see Cython underperform as dramatically as you do.

Comment: Thank you, your guess #1 makes perfect sance.